# autosuggest component for lengthy xmls in flex

Tags: apache-flex, autosuggest

I have a autosuggest library which I have been using in my project. I now have a textinput where I have to use this library. But this time the input has around 900,000 records. i.e, an xml having 900,000 nodes. When I used it with the component, it works but it has become slow probably because of filtering of the xmllistcollection on each key press. On each key press it takes 2-3 sec for refreshing. Is there a way to speed up the process?
I tested this xml on the local machine.

Comment: I think you should expect some slow down w/ 900K records.  I'd wait until the user types a few characters and then load a subset of the data.  I assume this is what apps--such as Firefox--or search engines--such as Google--do.

Answer (score 0):

For my autosuggest widgets, i use clearTimeout and setTimeout on keyUp to figure out when they've finished typing.  If they can hit a key every 750ms (not hard for a decent typist), then i'll wait until they're done typing before i perform any search (or filter in your case).

```
private var _timeoutID:uint=0;

private function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{

    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.ENTER)
    {
        //do search immediately
        clearTimeout(_timeoutID);
        doSearch()
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.ESCAPE)
    {
        //canel search
        clearTimeout(_timeoutID);
    }
    else
    {
        //begin timer
        clearTimeout(_timeoutID);
        _timeoutID = setTimeout(doSearch, 750 );
    }
}
private function doSearch():void
{
    //filter xmlcollection here
}
```